# AWS Cloud Formation Stack Status

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, aws-lambda

Hi am looking to get Cloud Formation Stack Status I tried with below code it's printing all the properties in the stack Object but I need only **StackStatus** please check with code and Response and help me to overcome this.
Advance appreciations

```
import boto3    

def lambda_handler(event, context):
client = boto3.client('cloudformation')
stack = client.describe_stacks(StackName='m6bf2b178-3bd2-ac06-88ef-
06545ba3fc74')
print(stack['Stacks'])
```

> Response is:

"[{'StackId': 'arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:*********:stack/m6bf2b178-3bd2-ac06-88ef-06545ba3fc74/10bc3e30-198f-11e8-bec2-50faeaee4499', 'StackName': 'm6bf2b178-3bd2-ac06-88ef-06545ba3fc74', 'Description': 'AWS CloudFormation Sample Template EC2InstanceWithSecurityGroupSample: Create an Amazon EC2 instance running the Amazon Linux AMI. The AMI is chosen based on the region in which the stack is run. This example creates an EC2 security group for the instance to give you SSH access.  This template creates an Amazon EC2 instance. You will be billed for the AWS resources used if you create a stack from this template.', 'Parameters': [{'ParameterKey': 'KeyName', 'ParameterValue': 'Test'}, {'ParameterKey': 'InstanceType', 'ParameterValue': 't2.micro'}], 'CreationTime': datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 24, 18, 18, 8, 756000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'RollbackConfiguration': {}, **'StackStatus': 'CREATE_COMPLETE'**, 'DisableRollback': False, 'NotificationARNs': [], 'Outputs': [{'OutputKey': 'InstanceId', 'OutputValue': 'i-04dd2a73e99f8d3d1', 'Description': 'InstanceId of the newly created EC2 instance'}, {'OutputKey': 'PublicIP', 'OutputValue': '34.227.162.158', 'Description': 'Public IP address of the newly created EC2 instance'}, {'OutputKey': 'AZ', 'OutputValue': 'us-east-1a', 'Description': 'Availability Zone of the newly created EC2 instance'}, {'OutputKey': 'PublicDNS', 'OutputValue': 'ec2-34-227-162-158.compute-1.amazonaws.com', 'Description': 'Public DNSName of the newly created EC2 instance'}], 'Tags': [], 'EnableTerminationProtection': False}]"

Answer (score 2):

```
import boto3

cloudformation = boto3.resource('cloudformation')
stack = cloudformation.Stack('StackName')
print(stack.stack_status)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since what you get as a response is a list of dictionaries, you can access the stack status with the following line:

```
stack_status = stack['Stacks'][0]['StackStatus']
print(stack_status)
```

It should ouput:

```
CREATE_COMPLETE
```